# Change the status bar color of the CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a ContactPicker and can control the color for my other ViewControllers in the project but cannot control the ContactsPickers
status bar color.

My goal is to get the status bar text to be white colored.

```
- (IBAction)btnSearch:(id)sender {

  //global statusbar color
  UINavigationBar.appearance.translucent = NO;
  UINavigationBar.appearance.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

  CNContactPickerViewController *contactPicker = [CNContactPickerViewController new];

  //local statusbar color
  contactPicker.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
  contactPicker.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

  contactPicker.delegate = self;

  contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactNamePrefixKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];

  [self presentViewController:contactPicker animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

**I have also found this in Xcode Docs:**
Apps default to using the new view controller-based status bar management system. To opt out of this, add a value of NO for the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key to your Info.plist.

When I have a global property to not control per view, I can manage
to get the ContactPicker status bar to have white color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying all kinds of approaches which did not work for my
situation:

**(1)**
in my Appdelegate I tried this, it had no effect:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
```

**(2)**
in my AppDelegate I have this but it had no effect:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.translucent = NO;
UINavigationBar.appearance.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

**(3)**
Just before presenting the ContactsController I had this (no effect):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

**(4)**
This too had no effect just before presenting the Controller:

```
contactPicker.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
contactPicker.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

**(5)**
**This worked** by extending the class and overriding the method "preferredStatusBarStyle":

**NOTE:** in my plist I have set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "YES"

*For all other ViewControllers simply setting the translucent and the barStyle of the NavigationCotroller to UIBarStyleBlack worked, but
not for the Contacts.*

.h

```
#import <ContactsUI/ContactsUI.h>

@interface ContactViewController : CNContactPickerViewController

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ContactViewController.h"

@interface ContactViewController ()

@end

@implementation ContactViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
   return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
@end
```